# how do i keep track of user info without having them log in?

Tags: django, django-views

I'm creating an online questionnaire, and I'd like each user to be able to take the questionnaire once. When a user visits my page, they will be required to fill out some personal info, which will be stored in a sql database with a random id. Then they will take the questionnaire and their answers will be linked to the stored id. They should not be able to access the questionnaire until they fill out this personal info.

Ideally, they will be able to leave the page and come back to complete the questionnaire whenever they like, but this is not necessary.

Could someone point me in the right direction of how to do this? I would know how to go about this if I were to create logins for users, but I don't want users to have to login. I feel that this should be possible, but am unclear what to search for to find info on how to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: distinct by IP or cookies, but thats bad idea. better go with the login.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Cookies and store the unique id in cookies and retrieve it everytime to identify the user.

You can use [Django's session framework](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/). Example code:

Setting a cookie:

```
def view(request):
  ...
  ...
  response.set_cookie( 'user_id', user_id )
```

Retrieving a cookie:

```
def view(request):
  ...
  if request.COOKIES.has_key( 'user_id' ):
    value = request.COOKIES[ 'user_id' ]
```

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the time a user can take between the first and the second part,
you can use session variables in PHP to generate an id and store it in the Database.
you can find the configuration for the max time of this variable once it's set in the php.ini file.
by checking the session variable you know if the user has completed the first form and in case it's false redirect to it.
cheers

Comment: OP is using Python, not PHP -.-

Comment: OP:"Could someone point me in the right direction of how to do this? "
I was just trying to help.